# JavaScript Compile Error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari, compiler-errors

I noticed a strange thing when writing some JS code. This compile error seems to happen across multiple browsers (tested: Chrome, IE, Safari). I am in no hurry for a solution but I could not figure out why this code won't compile:

```
    function fooBar1()//Compiles
    {
        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 1
        };
    }
    function fooBar2()//Compiles
    {
        return {x: 0, y: 1};
    }
    function fooBar3()//Compiles
    {
        return
        {
            x: 0
        };
    }
    function fooBar4()//Does not compile
    {
        return
        {
            x: 0,
            y: 1//Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : 
        };
    }
```

Comment: Did you try formatting that properly -> http://jsfiddle.net/MauPm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Javascript's *Automatic Semicolon Insertion* "feature".

I put the word "feature" in quotes because it's really anything but -- it's frankly a bit of a disaster; one of the worst design decisions I know of in a language.

Basically, the JS language is designed to have all statements ending with a semi-colon, but the original language design made allowances for coders who forgot it, and so if it sees a line break without a semi-colon, it tries to guess whether there should have been one there.

Unfortunately, there are some cases where this results in ambiguity and errors, and `return` statements are probably the worst for this.

In your last example, the `{` for the object being returned is on the line after the `return` statement. This is a classic case for this kind of bug. JS automatically inserts a semi-colon after `return`, and the the object that you intended to return is ignored.

Simple answer: just don't do it like this. Always put the object on the same line as the `return` statement. Memorise the fact that `return` needs the return data to be on the same line (or at least to start on the same line) as the `return` statement itself.

The closest you can get to your broken example and still have it work is shown by your first example.

```
return {
    x: 0,
    y: 1
};
```

As a final thought, you might want to consider running you JS code through a tool like [jsLint](http://www.jshint.com/), which will pick up errors like this (and other potential issues).

Comment: This is not correct. The `return` statement does not allow line terminators before the expression, regardless of semi-colons, as this rule applies before ASI; so you get an error for trying to use an object literal as a statement. Should also mention that `fooBar3` only 'compiles' because `{ x: 0 }` is actually a labeled block statement, not an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

bugs like these can really drive one crazy, can't they?

my guess is that javascript parser adds a semicolon right after return in fooBar4. (it "thinks" you wanted it there)

at least when I modify any of your working functions by adding semicolon after return, same syntax error will appear